# How to convert template.xml parameters value to lowercase when generating new objects from templates?

Tags: android, gradle

I've created a custom template with an initialization parameter whose value has to be used some times as is, other times in lowercase form.

This is the parameter definition coded in the file **template.xml** of the custom template:

```
<parameter
        id="itemClass"
        name="ListView Item Name"
        type="string"
        constraints="class|unique|nonempty"
        default="ItemClass"
        help="The name of the class of the ListView item" />
```

and it's used to generate both the java class file and a related xml layout file.

Being used as a class name, it is generally capitalized and that's not a problem for the java class file (i.e. MyItemClass.java).

The problem arises when the related xml layout file is created because its name, using the same parameter, doesn't comply with the all-lowercase rule applying to xml resource files (MyItemClass_layout.xml instead of myitemclass_layout.xml).

This are the build statements I'm using in the **recipe.xml.ftl** file of the template:

```
<instantiate from="root/src/app_package/ItemClass.${ktOrJavaExt}.ftl"
               to="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${itemClass}.java" />
<open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${itemClass}.${ktOrJavaExt}" />

<instantiate from="root/res/layout/item_layout.xml.ftl"
               to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${itemClass}_layout.xml" />
<open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${itemClass}_layout.xml" />
```

So I need something to de-capitalize ${itemClass} in the second statement in order to obtain a valid xml file name.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

According to an example that can be found on activities/MasterDetailFlow/globals.xml.ftl you can use lower_case to achieve that.

```
<instantiate from="root/src/app_package/ItemClass.${ktOrJavaExt}.ftl"
               to="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${itemClass}.java" />
<open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${itemClass}.${ktOrJavaExt}" />

<instantiate from="root/res/layout/item_layout.xml.ftl"
               to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${itemClass?lower_case}_layout.xml" />
<open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${itemClass?lower_case}_layout.xml" />
```

A full list of allowed functions of FreeMarker can be [found here](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html).